# weird bug when i used asyncpg in my aiohttp app

Tags: python, aiohttp, asyncpg

i started developing my app with aiopg to access data in postgres and everything was OK , i decided to replace it with asyncpg .

this is one of my view function :

```
@router.get('/{post}')
@aiohttp_jinja2.template("view.html")
async def view_post(request):
    ret = {'id':'1','owner':'shooooobi','editor':'shooooobi','title':'new_title','text':'nothing'}

    return {"post":ret}
```

it is a simple view and is ok but when i added some asyncpg code like following ,i added line 4 to 7 line by line and run app ...

```
@router.get('/{post}')
@aiohttp_jinja2.template("view.html")
async def view_post(request):
    pg  = request.config_dict["PG"]
    post_id = request.match_info["post"]
    con = pg.acquire()
    cur = con.cursor('SELECT id, owner, editor, title, text FROM mshma.posts where id=$1',post_id)
    ret = {'id':'1','owner':'shooooobi','editor':'shooooobi','title':'new_title','text':'nothing'}

    return {"post":ret}
```

line 7 cause that i received following text in my web page.

```
context should be mapping, not <class 'set'>
```

when i comment this line  (line 7) my view function works as expected .
what is the problem??

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `await` for **async** calls; here is a snippet on how to acquire a connection from the pool, run a query and release the connection back to the pool

```py
conn = await pg.acquire()
try:
    result = await conn.fetchrow("SELECT id, owner, editor, title, text FROM mshma.posts where id=$1", post_id)
finally:
    await pg.release(conn)
# do something with result (which is an asyncpg.Record object)
```

Comment: it doesn't work !!, i think asyncpg change something in aiohttp_jinja2 .

Comment: The error message `context should be mapping` does point to a jinja issue; try to return the data retrieved using asyncpg without the jinja2 decorator like: `return json.dumps(dict(result))`

Comment: Try: `return {"post": dict(result)}` where result is from my above snippet

Comment: i just convert parameter to integer : int(post_id) , now it works ! it didn't show me errore until i delete jinja2 template .thanks .

Answer (score 0):

executing this query is failed , because the parameter id column is integer and the parameter post_id is string , errors wouldn't be shown when we use jinja2 template!!.
 we just need to convert post_id to integer (`int(post_id)`)